# Can Flash load static .JPG files without crossdomain.xml policies?

Tags: flash, crossdomain.xml

I'm doing a Flash Banner for an ADv campaing. Since the max swf file size allowed is very low, I'm trying to load external JPG images from the main server.

Reading the crossdomain policies for Flash movies I see that:

> You cannot load variables or XML data
>   into a Flash movie from another
>   domain.

It's the same with static files as Jpg images?

I'm testing the banner with various results: looking in Firebug, images are always loaded, but sometimes they appear, sometimes not, sometimes only the first time (it's a loop). There are no warnings however.

Loading the Banner with the same domain as the static images always works.

I also tried to put a `crossdomain.xml` file on the domain that serves the static images, but problem seems to continue (maybe Flash cache that request somewhere...How can I check that?)

So, I still trying to know if the problem is related to the crossdomain policies.

Comment: Are you getting any sandbox security errors thats usually an indicator of a incorrectly configured crossdomain.xml?

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is loading static JPEG images then you shouldn't need a `crossdomain.xml` file. However, your are fairly limited to what you can do with the images (no access to bytes) and the images have to be loaded using the `Loader` class.

Comment: @achairapat I didn't realize that you were using ActionScript 2.0. I don't have much experience with that version so I can't with confidence say what loadClip() behavior with respect to `crossdomain.xml` is supposed to be. But if you test it and it works, that should be good enough. I know for sure that for ActionScript 3.0 it is the expected behavior.